# Is there any equivalent of fsync/fdatasync for symbolic links?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, posix, symlink

What is the proper way to ensure that a newly written symbolic link is saved to disk? I was doing some crash testing, and I see that in the case of an abnormal shut down, it may not be. You can see this quite simply:

```
ln -s existing_file link_name
```

and then forcing a shutdown. Specifically, I am asking if there exists a system call for this purpose.

Comment: Try calling `fsync()` on the directory. See if it works.

Comment: Try [`sync(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html)

Comment: @Joshua why would that work? A symlink is not a directory entry.

Comment: @Barmar so nothing just for symlinks? must force everything to disk and incur the wait?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know. I think filesystem drivers generally try to minimize how long metadata is cached.

Comment: *ln* (without the "-s", as in your example) doesn't create a symlink at all. It creates a hard link.

Comment: @user129393192: `fsync()` on a directory entry fixes a lot of "can't sync that" problems. Assuming the filesystem doesn't violate its ordered writes constraint when calling `fsync()` on a directory entry it will work, but that's not a given.

Comment: How do you mean @Joshua ? If a symbolic link has its own inode, which is (in `ext` implementation at least), not the same block as the directory entries of an unrelated directory

Comment: I think what is meant is to call `fsync()` on the directory containing the symlink, not the directory of the symlink target (or some unrelated directory).

Comment: @user129393192: `open(...) write(...) close(...) rename(...) fsync(directory);` reliably syncs the file contents as well.

Comment: Calling `fsync` on the directory ensures its meta information and directory entries are written to disks. How would that work for a symbolic link that has its own inode and possibly contents? Something like `write` doesn't reliably sync a file from my understanding, you have to call `fsync` on the file for that.